# Iterate through list returned by python keyword in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a function in my (python) keyword library that returns a list, but when I pass it into the robot testcase, I get the error "Value of variable @{LIST} is not list or list-like". Here is my code

Robot code:

```
Generate Data
    @{LIST}=    Create Data 

Do Thing For All Values In List
    :FOR    ${value}    IN  @{LIST} 
    \   Do The Thing     ${value}
```

Python code for this:

```
def create_data():
    data = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        data_val = do_a_bunch_of_selenium_automation(i)
        data.append(data_val)
    return data
```

How do I do this correctly? Thanks all.

Comment: You have a function called `Create Data`? Or perhaps something like `CreateData()` or `Create_Data()` ?

Comment: Can edit your question and add the Python function `Create Data`?

Comment: @Yunnosch, yes. In my case, the function name create_data(). I'm sure it is running, because (in my specific case), it does a few more things than just generate a list

Comment: @Yunnosch: no, it should not be `create_data()`. This code is the correct syntax.

Comment: @BryanOakley I probably got lost here. Was looking for python syntax in something clearly labeled not to be. Thanks for the kind note. (actually I just discovered that the label is younger... but still my fault for getting so lost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code in your question, You are properly iterating over a list. However, you're creating the data in one test case and then trying to use it in another. The data is in a local variable in that first test case.

If you want to share data between test cases, you need to set the variable as a test suite variable, which you can do with the built-in keyword [Set suite variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable)

```
Generate Data
    @{LIST}=    create data
    set suite variable  @{LIST}
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

To be honest your examples work for me. Made a few additions to get to a working example but nothing major:

**ListCreationLibrary.py**

```
class ListCreationLibrary(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_data(self):
        data = []
        for i in range(0, 10):
            data_val = self.do_a_bunch_of_selenium_automation(i)
            data.append(data_val)
        return data

    def do_a_bunch_of_selenium_automation(self, i):
        return  "some_string" + str(i)
```

**test_script.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ListCreationLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${list_example}    Create Data
    Do Thing For All Values In List    ${list_example}

*** Keywords ***
Do Thing For All Values In List
    [Arguments]    ${LIST}
    :FOR    ${value}    IN  @{LIST} 
    \   Do The Thing     ${value}

Do The Thing
    [Arguments]    ${value}
    Log    ${value}
```

Put the two files in the same directory and you should be OK.